# Any way to disable "A stop job is running" in Debian 10

Tags: debian, systemd, proxmox

edit2: This question keep getting closed with links which point to completely irrelevant posts so giving up on it.

edit: I'm asking how to disable/kill the Stop Job, not change the time to SIGKILL (which apparently isn't working either since 90s is the default).

I have a few Debian 10 systems (Proxmox) which take anywhere from 5 minutes to forever to reboot.

Sometimes I need to drive into the DC and physically hit the power button. The keyboard is always unresponsive at this point. I don't know if USB is already disabled in the reboot process or what. The holdup is always Systemd with "A stop job is running". Today it appears to be the swap partition.

[image: 15 minutes to "never" to reboot]

Any way to put a kill-switch on the stop jobs? I don't care if swap gets hosed due to a dirty unmount - At this point, I'd rather just fsck -Cf after every reboot and mount swap by hand.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503058/what-is-the-delay-between-sigterm-and-sigkill-on-shutdown/503064#503064

Comment: Does this post answer your case in Debian too? - [Interactively terminate "A stop job is running" at shutdown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608422/interactively-terminate-a-stop-job-is-running-at-shutdown)

Comment: Umm.. not really. Unless I'm missing something, those links don't explain how to kill the Stop Job which is what I'm asking about. It's clearly broken since 90s is the default time until SIGKILL, which apparently doesn't work either.

Comment: @Nstevens Just in case you're missing something... do you know about "Magic SysRq REISUB"? If not, [RTFM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_shortcuts#Kernel_(SysRq)). If you know, are you saying it didn't work or are you saying it's not your preferred solution?

Comment: @dungarian - sysrq works fine if the keyboard is responsive but oftentimes it is not at this point in the reboot. I issue `I` `U` `S` before `B` and usually try that on the remote KVM before driving into the DC. It does work sometimes however which is a relief.

Comment: How is this question a duplicate? The suggested posts don't provide the answer being asked here...